# prove for P(n)= (n+2)(n-1)/2 using principle of induction

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Any idea how to prove this with induction? If you plug in numerical values for n the LHS is not equal to the RHS. What is going on here?

The question is: 1+2+3+4+---------+=[(n+2)(n-1)]/2

Comment: Something was lost in transcription.  $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = \frac {n(n+1)}{2}$  should it be $2 + 3 + \cdots + n$?

Comment: The thing is my teacher told us to try this question and it honestly makes no sense. There might have been an error in what he tried to convey but that's what's written in the question.

Comment: But even with n(n+1)/2 the LHS doesn't seem to add up.

Comment: Probably the sum starts from $n=2$, not $n=1$.

Comment: Is the LHS $1+2+3+\cdots + n$?

Answer (score 2):

If your propositions is

$2+3+\cdots + n = \frac {(n+2)(n-1)}{2}$

does the LHS equal the RHS?

Try n = 5

$2+3+4+5 = 14 \\
\frac{(5+2)(5-1)}{2} = 14$

But that is not a proof

Proof by induction.

base case n = 2

$2 = \frac {(2+2)(1)}{2} = 2$

Inductive hypothesis.

Suppose,

$2+3+\cdots + n = \frac {(n+2)(n-1)}{2}$

We must show that

$2+3+\cdots + n + n+1 = \frac {(n+1+2)(n+1-1)}{2} = \frac {(n+3)(n)}{2}$

Based on the inductive hypothesis

$2+3+\cdots + n + n+1\\
\frac {(n+2)(n-1)}{2} + n+1\\
\frac {n^2 +n - 2 + 2n + 2}{2} \\
\frac {(n +3)(n)}{2}$

QED

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where $p(n)\implies p(n+1)$ but $p(n)$ is false because there is no starting point.